# How to get all elements in the list from JSON in python code

Tags: python, json

trying to find out correct syntax to traverse through through the list to get all values and insert into oracle.

edit:
Below is the json structure  :

```
[{
  "publishTime" : "2021-11-02T20:18:36.223Z",
  "data" : {
    "DateTime" : "2021-11-01T15:10:17Z",
    "Name" : "x1",
    "frtb" : {
      "code" : "set1"
    },
    "mainAccounts" : [ {
      "System" : {
        "identifier" : {
          "domain" : "System",
          "id" : "xxx"
        },
        "name" : "TEST1"
      },
      "Account" : "acc1"
    }, {
      "System" : {
        "identifier" : {
          "domain" : "System",
          "id" : "xxx"
        },
        "name" : "TEST2"
      },
      "Account" : "acc2"
    }, {
      "System" : {
        "identifier" : {
          "domain" : "System",
          "id" : "xxx"
  
        },
        "name" : "TEST3"
      },
      "Account" : "acc3"
    }],
    "sub" : {
      "ind" : false,
      "identifier" : {
        "domain" : "ops",
        "id" : "1",
        "version" : "1"
      }]
```

My python code :

```
insert_statement = """INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (:1,:2)"""

r =requests.get(url, cert=(auth_certificate, priv_key), verify=root_cert, timeout=3600)

data=json.loads(r.text)

myrows = []


for item in data:
 
  try:
        name = (item.get("data").get("Name"))
  except AttributeError:
        name=''
  try:
        account= (item.get("data").get("mainAccounts")[0].get("Account") )
  except TypeError:
        account=''

  rows=(name,account)
  myrows.append(rows)

cursor.executemany(insert_statement,myrows)  
connection_target.commit()
```

with the above i only get first value for 'account' in list i.e. ("acc1") , how to get all the values i.e. (acc1,acc2,acc3) ?

I have tried below with no success :

try:
Account = (item.get("data").get("mainAccounts")[0].get("Account") for item in data["mainAccounts")
except TypeError:
Account= ''

please advise.Appreciate your help always.

Comment: `for item in data: accounts = [act["Account"] for act in item.get("data", {}).get("mainAccounts", [])]` ? Can I ask why you're expecting a `TypeError` here?

Comment: sorry says invalid syntax

Comment: Where are you putting it? For your first line `for item in data:`. For your second line `accounts = [act["Account"] for act in item.get("data", {}).get("mainAccounts", [])]`. No `try`/`except`. Just those 2 lines of code after your definition of `data`.

Comment: If you still have issues with it, I'll post it as a formatted answer.

Comment: sorry yes i had try/except. I'm trying to input this data into oracle , now i get "cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: arrays of arrays are not supported by the OCI

Comment: Are you getting the data you need from the `json`? "Inputting your data in Oracle" is not part of your question. If you have another question in addition to this one, please post it separately.

Comment: yes from json. thanks will check below.

Comment: edited my post  with all the information. Hope this helps.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
my_json = json.load(open("my_json.json", 'r'))

>>> mainAccounts = my_json['mainAccounts']
>>> for account in mainAccounts:
...    account_name = account['Account']
...    system_domain = account['System']['identifier']['domain']
...    system_id = account['System']['identifier']['id']
...    system_name = account['System']['name']
...    print(f"\n======={account_name}==========")
...    print(f"System domain: {system_domain}")
...    print(f"System id: {system_id}")
...    print(f"System name: {system_name}")




=======acc1==========
System domain: System
System id: xxx
System name: TEST1

=======acc2==========
System domain: System
System id: xxx
System name: TEST2

=======acc3==========
System domain: System
System id: xxx
System name: TEST3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Oracle before so I'm going to assume your SQL statement is correct and requires a `tuple` of `(name, account_number)`.

```
data = [
    {
        "publishTime" : "2021-11-02T20:18:36.223Z",
        "data" : {
            "DateTime" : "2021-11-01T15:10:17Z",
            "Name" : "x1",
            "frtb" : {
                "code" : "set1"
            },
            "mainAccounts" : [ 
                {
                    "System" : {
                        "identifier" : {
                            "domain" : "System",
                            "id" : "xxx"
                        },
                        "name" : "TEST1"
                    },
                    "Account" : "acc1"
                }, {
                    "System" : {
                        "identifier" : {
                            "domain" : "System",
                            "id" : "xxx"
                        },
                        "name" : "TEST2"
                    },
                    "Account" : "acc2"
                }, {
                    "System" : {
                        "identifier" : {
                            "domain" : "System",
                            "id" : "xxx"
                        },
                        "name" : "TEST3"
                    },
                    "Account" : "acc3"
                }
            ],
            "sub" : {
                "ind" : False,
                "identifier" : {
                    "domain" : "ops",
                    "id" : "1",
                    "version" : "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

myrows = []
for item in data:
    accounts = [
        (act["System"]["name"], act["Account"]) 
        for act in item.get("data", {}).get("mainAccounts", [])
    ]
    myrows.extend(accounts)
    
print(myrows) # [('TEST1', 'acc1'), ('TEST2', 'acc2'), ('TEST3', 'acc3')]
```

And then assuming it's in the correct format.

```
cursor.executemany(insert_statement, myrows)
```

How it works:

This line gets your top level `dict` and assigns it to `item`.
I used a `for` loop in case there are multiple `dict`s in the `list`.

```
for item in data:
```

The `list` comprehension is a bit more complex. But it can be translated to this.

```
accounts = []
for act in item.get("data", {}).get("mainAccounts", []):
    name = act["System"]["name"]
    account = act["Account"]
    accounts.append(name, account)
```

Or simplified even more:

```
data_dict = item.get("data", {})
main_accounts_list = data_dict.get("mainAccounts", [])
for act in main_accounts_list:
    # the rest of the code
```

I used `dict.get()` with an empty `dict` and `list` as a default so that even if the keys do not exist, it will still be able to process the subsequent `.get` and iteration without erroring.

Finally, you `extend` `my_rows` rather than `append` so you add don't get a `list` of `list`.

```
myrows.extend(accounts)
```

Comment: thanks @Axe319  for the explanation. This prints out correct results , but when trying to insert i get "killed" message on my terminal. I didn't think it was memory as the system has good amount of resources. I'm not sure what could cause this..

Comment: thank you @axe319 for the above. I was able to solve the error. I had to change the syntax of other fields similar to above.